# TensorFlow Dataset API Parsing Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the TensorFlow Dataset API to parse a CSV file and run a logistic regression. I'm following the example from the TF documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py).

The following code snippet shows how I am setting up the model:

```
def input_fn(path, num_epochs, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(path)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_table, num_parallel_calls=12)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset.batch(batch_size)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels

def parse_table(value):
    cols = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=TAB_COLUMN_DEFAULTS)
    indep_vars = dict(zip(CSV_COLS, cols))
    y = indep_vars.pop('y')
    return indep_vars, y

def build_indep_vars():
    continuous_vars = [
        tf.feature_column.numeric_column(x, shape=1) for x in CONT_COLS]
    categorical_vars = [
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
            x, hash_bucket_size=100) for x in CAT_COLS]
    return categorical_vars + continuous_vars
```

When calling `lr.train(input_fn = lambda: input_fn(data_path, 1, 100))` (note: batch size is 100) I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: Feature (key: V1) cannot have rank 0. Give: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

So I'm assuming this means one of the `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` calls is getting a scalar value which it doesn't like. However, I cannot figure out why this is the case. I've set `batch_size` to a positive integer and according to the documentation the shape of the NDarray resulting from `tf.feature_column.numeric_column` should be `1Xbatch_size` by default. Can anyone explain why TensorFlow is returning this error?

I'm sure this question has a simple answer that will make me feel stupid for not figuring it out, but after spending some time on this I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is raised because the `tf.feature_column` methods expect the input to be batched, and 
I think the cause is a simple typo, which is dropping out the [`Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) transformation. Replace the `dataset.batch(batch_size)` with the following line:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Calling any of the `tf.data.Dataset` transformations methods (e.g. `Dataset.map()`, `Dataset.repeat()`, `Dataset.batch()`) does not modify the object on which you called those methods. Instead, these methods return a *new* `Dataset` object that you can either use for further transformations, or to make an `Iterator`.

Comment: Indeed the problem was not assigning the output of `dataset.batch(batch_size)`. Thanks!